# Jquery Autocomplete multiple PHP Arrays as different categories

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I can successfully use a php array as results for autocomplete and be able to click on them individually. However, I now also want to use a second PHP array and have that as a separate category. The first category will be usernames and the second teams. Below is my code:

```
// query to find usernames for the search bar
  $userSearch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");


  $userSearch->execute([]);

    ($userSearchResult = $userSearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));

// query to find teams for the search bar
  $teamSearch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT teamName FROM teams");


  $teamSearch->execute([]);

    ($teamSearchResult = $teamSearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Assign php generated json to JavaScript variable
   var userSearch = <?php echo json_encode($userSearchResult); ?>;
   var teamSearch = <?php echo json_encode($teamSearchResult); ?>;

    $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});

$(function() {
    $("#searchBox").catcomplete({
        source: [{"label":userSearch, "category":"username"}, {"label":teamSearch, "category":"teams"}]
    });
});
</script>
```

This is as close as i have had it to working. The problem is that the category is shown correctly but then the results are listed as one long array with a comma. So instead of:

```
usernames
   username 1
   username 2
   username 3
teams
   team 1
   team 2
   team 3
```

I'm getting:

```
usernames 
   username 1,username 2,username 3
teams 
   team 1,team 2,team 3
```

I was hoping my use of implode in the variables would sort this but it never did.

if i just use one variable as my source without categories like so:

```
source: userSearch
```

i do successfully get a list of usernames and this shows:

```
username 1
username 2
username 3
```

But this does not contain categories or the second array needed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why would you need to use `implode`, there's already a `json_encode` available, duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of

```
<?php echo  implode('","',$userSearchResult); ?>
```

your array will have just one element.

You need to encode arrays with `json_encode`:

```
var userSearch = <?php echo json_encode($userSearchResult); ?>;
var teamSearch = <?php echo json_encode($teamSearchResult); ?>;
```

According to manual - you should set your data as:

```
var data = [
  { label: "anders", category: "" },
  { label: "andreas", category: "" },
  { label: "antal", category: "" },
  { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
  { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
  { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
  { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
];
```

So in your case you need to modify your php arrays:

```
$userSearch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");
$userSearch->execute([]);
$userSearchResult = [];
while ($row = $userSearch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $userSearchResult[] = [
        'label' =>  $row['username'],
        'category' =>  "username"
    ];
}
// same to teamnames
$teamSearchResult = [];

$result = array_merge(
    $userSearchResult,
    $teamSearchResult
);
```

And javascript:

```
$("#searchBox").catcomplete({
    source: <?php echo json_encode($result)?>
});
```

Comment: you are correct in the use of json_encode, however this hasn't changed the results. They are still shown with comma's

Comment: First of all thanks for the great answer! secondly, sorry I'm back haha. i know this is a separate question but rather than me starting another i thought I'd ask you as you seem a lot more knowledgeable than me! the list shows up perfectly. only i can't select an option with the mouse or keys. I've tried loads of options with the select: function but to know avail. select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#searchBox").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            } didn't work aswell as other things i've tried.

Comment: I just took a quick look at docs to answer you first question, so it's hard for me to tell what's the cause of your second error. I believe you can answer a new question and hope it will help you)